# How do you create a customized cost function in Keras using an additional image-dependent argument?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create a custom cost function in Keras that uses an additional parameter that changes with each image. For every image the model is being trained on, there is an associated parameter, call it alpha, that is related to how important that particular image is. If there are 100 images, there are 100 alpha values, and the order matters. How would I implement this in a custom MSE cost function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.keras.Model.fit` has a `sample_weight`parameter (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), this might be of help. I'm assuming this also exists in native Keras (no idea though).

Comment: I believe this solves my problem. Do you know if the shuffle option in 'fit' will shuffle weights accordingly?

Comment: I would be _really_ surprised if it didn't. That would be a bug.

Comment: I had seen some discussion on similar methods possibly causing issues but I can confirm now that shuffle works fine in this context.